# Sum case in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query get total sales for certain outlet.

Output:

```
SourceName       Amount
------------------------
Call Center      2997.00
Delivero Credit  5879.00
Eat Easily Cash    57.00
```

If I have a list of outlets, outlet 1 and outlet 2 for example, I want so to get total sales by source for each outlet and if there no sales sales amount value should be zero so out put will be.

```
SourceName      outlet 1   outlet 2
-----------------------------------
Call Center      2997.00    500
Delivero Credit  5879.00      0
Eat Easily Cash    57.00     66
```

The issue on the below query it double sum `DeliveryCharge`
it should be  `SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge - ((SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice))) * Orders.Discount / 100)`

Updated query:

```
SELECT
    s.SourceName,
    SUM(CASE
           WHEN o.OutletID ='1' THEN ((ord.Quantity * ord.UnitPrice) + ordd.DeliveryCharge)
           ELSE 0
        END) AS [Outlet 1],
    SUM(CASE
           WHEN o.OutletID ='1' THEN ((ord.Quantity * ord.UnitPrice) + ordd.DeliveryCharge)
           ELSE 0
        END) AS [Outlet 2]
FROM 
    dbo.Orders ordd
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Outlets o ON ordd.OutletID = o.OutletID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OrderDetails ord ON ord.OrderID = ordd.OrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Sources s ON s.SourceID = ordd.SourceID
WHERE  
    ordd.OrderID NOT IN (SELECT CanceledOrders.OrderID
                         FROM CanceledOrders)
    AND ordd.OrderDate BETWEEN '2017-05-1 10:00:00.000' AND '2017-06-1 04:00:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    s.SourceID, s.SourceName
ORDER BY
    s.SourceName
```

Comment: You need to show us some data here.  With a query involving 4 tables and 3 joins, it is difficult to guess what your data might be.

Comment: see the update pls ..

Answer (score 1):

You are currently grouping twice by the source name, which makes no sense to me.  That aside, I think you can get the output you want by removing the outlet name from `GROUP BY` and instead pivoting on that column.  In addition, I refactored your query to aggregate order details in a subquery, for each order.  This should get around the problem of duplication which you were seeing for delivery charge and possibly other fields.

```
WITH MyGroupCte AS (
    SELECT
        s.SourceName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN out.OutletName = 'outlet 1'
                 THEN ((1 - (o.Discount / 100)) * od.OrderPrice) + o.DeliveryCharge
                 ELSE 0 END) AS [outlet 1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN out.OutletName = 'outlet 2'
                 THEN ((1 - (o.Discount / 100)) * od.OrderPrice) + o.DeliveryCharge
                 ELSE 0 END) AS [outlet 2]
    FROM dbo.Orders AS o
    INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets AS out
        ON o.OutletID = out.OutletID
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            OrderID,
            SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) AS orderPrice
        FROM dbo.OrderDetails
        GROUP BY OrderId
    ) od
        ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS s
        ON s.SourceID = o.SourceID
    WHERE
        out.OutletID = '6' AND
        o.OrderID NOT IN (SELECT OrderID FROM CanceledOrders) AND
        o.OrderDate
            BETWEEN '2017-05-1 10:00:00.000' AND '2017-06-1 04:00:00.000'
    GROUP BY
        o.OrderID,
        s.SourceName
)

SELECT
    SourceName,
    [outlet 1],
    [outlet 2]
FROM MyGroupCte;
```

Please consider using aliases, which make your query much easier to read and format.

Comment: and also i am summing SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) delivery charge will be added

Comment: You gave us no data to go by.  My answer is reasonable given the information you provided.